# Is that the right way to add digest header in QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: authentication, hash, qnetworkaccessmanager

Could you help me about QNetworkAccessManager. I am trying to make an digest authentication in C++ QNetworkAccessManager, I couldn't a way to send the request without calculating the digest data. So I am doing the request with calculating the md5 . Does anybody know?  Is that the right way to add the header of digest response in QNetworkAccessManager.

Thanks,

```
  QString  G_username =  QString::fromUtf8(_userName.c_str());
  QString  G_realm = QString::fromUtf8(_realm.c_str());
  QString  G_nonce = QString::fromUtf8(_nonce.c_str());
  QString  G_uri = QString::fromUtf8(urlAfterIp.c_str());
  QString  G_response = QString::fromUtf8(ha3.c_str());
  QString  G_qop = QString::fromUtf8(_qop.c_str());
  QString  G_nc = QString::fromUtf8((_ncString).c_str());
  QString  G_cnonce = QString::fromUtf8(_cnonce.c_str());
    
  QEventLoop loop;
  QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
  QNetworkRequest networkRequest;
  networkRequest.setUrl(QUrl("http://172.16.101.68/reset"));

  //networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), digestValueToAdd.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Digest username"), G_username.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("realm"), G_realm.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("nonce"), G_nonce.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("uri"), G_uri.toUtf8());
  
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("algorithm"), "MD5");
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("response"), G_response.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("qop"), G_qop.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("nc"), G_nc.toUtf8());
  networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("cnonce"), G_cnonce.toUtf8());

  QLabel *label = new QLabel();
  QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(networkRequest);
     

  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
          label, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),
          label, SLOT(slotOnRequestCompleted()));
  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
          label, SLOT(slotOnRequestError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
          label, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

  QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

  loop.exec();

  QByteArray dataReceived = reply->readAll();
  QString dataReply(dataReceived);
```

Comment: t seems to be; It is the correct way to add the digest header,   >>>   
digestResponse = "Digest username=\"" + _userName + "\"" + ", realm=\"" + _realm + "\"" + ", nonce=\"" + _nonce + "\"" + ", uri=\"" + urlAfterIp +"\"" + ", algorithm=MD5" + ", response=" + "\"" + ha3 +"\"" + ", qop=" + _qop + ", nc=" + _ncString + ", cnonce=\"" +_cnonce + "\""                              networkRequest.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), digestResponse.c_str());                                                                                                                  >>> but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, right way of adding the digest header is:

```
 digestResponse = "Digest username=\"" + _userName  + "\"" + ", realm=\"" + _realm 
    + 
    "\"" + ", nonce=\"" + _nonce + "\""
                   + ", uri=\"" + urlAfterIp +"\"" + ", algorithm=MD5" + ", response=" 
    + 
    "\"" + ha3  +"\"" + ", qop=" + _qop + ", nc="
                   + _ncString + ", cnonce=\"" +_cnonce + "\"";



   QEventLoop loop;

   QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
   QNetworkRequest networkRequest;
   networkRequest.setUrl(QUrl("http://172.16.101.68/reset"));

   networkRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", digestResponse.c_str());
```